# Are Automated Refineries/Extractors as fast as three workers?

Tags: starcraft-2

In both the Wings of Liberty and Heart of the Swarm campaigns there are research options for automated refineries/extractors, which allow vespene gas to be harvested without a worker.  This has obvious benefits, such as freeing more supply for combat units and allowing long-distance vespene gas harvesting, but I'm curious how fast the gas actually collects.

Assuming the command center/hatchery is as close as possible to the vespene geyser, will three workers harvest gas quicker than, slower than, or just as quickly as the automated building?

Comment: Very good question. Hard to test too, will try to benchmark! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Automated extractors harvest **at the same rate** as extractors that have 3 drones.

I tested this on the Hand of Darkness mission. I choose this mission because it ends at 5:12 if you don't kill the first hybrid and you start with drones and one extractor.

I was able to harvest a total of 696 gas by 5:12 with and without the Automated Extractors ability. Turning on Vaspene Efficiency allowed me to gather a total of 845 gas with and without Automated Extractors by 5:12.

## Results

```
+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| Total Gas Harvested     | Vespene Efficiency | No Vespene Efficiency |
+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| Automated Extractors    | 845                | 696                   |
| No Automated Extractors | 845                | 696                   |
+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

*Note*: The mission starts you off with 100 free gas, so the net gain is 100 gas less than the totals I posted above.

Comment: I like seeing reproducible results! :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no evidence pointing towards faster extraction from either the Refinery or the Extractor. It is not a "gas-equivalent" to a Terran Mule.

The point of this upgrade: (which you point out yourself)

- To spare the 6 or more food supplies to help you get a larger army.
  (or to have SCVs or Drones mine instead - increasing the amount of minerals in the early game)
- To take gas with no Command center or Hatchery nearby.

Comment: I think he understands the point of the Automated Refinery/Extractor, he just wants to know whether 3 workers harvest vespene faster, slower or at the same rate as the Automated refinery by itself

Comment: As stated: "There is no evidence pointing towards faster extraction from either the Refinery or the Extractor. It is not a "gas-equivalent" to a Terran Mule."

Comment: Being a gas equivalent to a Terran Mule would entail allowing *faster* gas harvesting. The question was whether it was faster, *slower*, or the same speed. You've only eliminated 1 of 3 possible scenarios.

Comment: Sorry about that. In other words - the auto-mated Refinery or Extractor are just as fast as 3 working SCVs or Drones vise versa. They arent slower or faster. They have the same collection speed!

Comment: @AtlasEU Source?

Comment: It sounds like you're just guessing. Why not just not answer and let someone answer that knows?